# Methods for evaluating a geo-experimental research design (DiD, CausalImpact or a third option?)

Tags: time-series, experiment-design, causality, difference-in-difference, causalimpact

I'm doing my undergraduate thesis on an experimental design of the incrementality of clicks using Google Ads vs not using Google Ads.

I've created a geo-experimental design, where I've made a split of cities in a country into two equal groups through stratified sampling to create two as equal groups as possible. Then I'll not show ads for one of the groups, while showing the ads for the other one. I've plotted the time-series between the two groups over a 2 month period prior to the intervention, to look for correlation and similarities between the two groups on a daily basis (see attached plot).

[image]

Then I got into some doubt about how I should evaluate my research design when doing the actual intervention because the two time series are both non-stationary. Through my plot, I can see a clear correlation between the series and they both have the same trend over time. I've also conducted an Engle-Granger test for cointegration, and can conclude that the relationship is stationary over time. I'm aware that I can't measure the relationship after the intervention, but I assume that the same underlying relationship between the groups will stay the same.

What would be the best way to measure the effect of the intervention on the two groups? I've looked a lot into causal effect design with DiD and the CausalImpact-package by Google. I especially like the way the CausalImpact-packages is using a BSTS-method, but it seems a bit complicated with the math behind it, and they will often use more predictors/controls than just the one I'll be using. Would there be an even more appropriate or even simpler method of evaluating my design when using just 1 predictor? Or should I go with DiD or the CausalImpact method?